# Sitecore Content Hub One with inbuild Experience Edge support?

Tags: content-hub

Sitecore has just launched its new product **"Content Hub One"** for headless development. Has it inbuild Experience Edge support?

I know we can also create headless applications with existing content hub CMP module with experience edge but that comes with separate license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct - actually Experience Edge is not tagged as a separate feature with Content Hub One. We offer globally distributed GraphQL APIs powered by Experience Edge. It is just a part of the Content Hub One offer and price.

(This was from the Sitecore Product team)

Comment: Thank you @Richard Seal